# How to disable filter attribute all over the site in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https, attributes

I have an ASP.NET MVC site and for some controllers and actions attribute `RequireHttps` applied.

Is it possible to disable this attribute all over the site without modifying all files with this attribute?

E.g. in `FilterConfig` such attributes may be enabled, but may they be disabled?

Comment: Even it is possible it doesn't worth to try. if it all about the testing on http environment - it won't be real testing. for test purposes you can generate a test certificate and apply it to you test host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Global.asax file add the following line of code to the Application_Start Method

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

Now, if you want to turn this off, you can just comment it out. Or wrap it with a compiler directive so its not set in debug mode.